# Edge detection de uma frame

Tags: matlab, vídeo

Eu tenho um vídeo, e preciso para cada *frame* fazer *edge detection* (`prewitt`), pois eu preciso só dos contornos da minha área de interesse.

Após fazer o *edge detection* de cada *frame*, eu preciso medir a área do contorno para cada *frame* e extrair os valores.

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Ja exprimentas-te fazer essa pergunta aqui?
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
Ou aqui?
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ De certeza que te ajudam ;)